# How to retrieve elements of pointer array

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

double t = 1800.;//s
double dt = 30.;//s

double temp = 293.;//K
double visc = 0.1;//cP=10^-3 Pa*s
double diam = 1.0;//micro meter=10^-6 m

double x0 = 0.;
double v0 = 0.;

int idg;//random seed
double arr[61]={NULL};

int main() {
    srand((int)time(0));
    int np = int(t / dt)+1;
    double *x;
    double tt;

    void brown(double*,const int);

    x = new double[np]; 

    brown(x,np);

    int l = 1;
    while (l <= 100) {
        x = new double[np];
        brown(x, np);
        for (int m = 1; m < np; m++) { //x从1开始，到np次数
             arr[m] += pow(x[m] - x[m - 1], 2.0); //Error
        }
    delete[] x;
    }

    for (int j = 1; j <= 60; j++) {
        total = arr[j] / 100;
        cout << total << endl;
    }


    return 0;
}

void brown(double *x,const int np){
    const double kb = 1.380649;
    const double masse = 1.0;//micro gram=10^-9 kg
    double d = 0.1;//s
    double kbT, A, stm, gamma;
    double c1,c2;
    int f,nt;
    double *xx, *vv, *r;

    double gaussnoise(int);

    kbT = kb * temp / 100.;
    A = 2.0 * kbT * 3.0 * 3.1415926 * visc * diam;
    stm = sqrt(kbT / masse);
    gamma = A / (2.0 * kbT);
    c1 = 1. / (1. + gamma / masse * d);
    c2 = d * sqrt(2. * gamma / masse / d);

    f = int(dt / d);

    if (f == 0) {
        d = dt;
        f = 1;
        nt = np;
    }
    else {
        d = dt / f;
        nt = np * f;
    }

    xx = new double[nt];
    vv = new double[nt];
    r = new double[nt];

    xx[0] = x0 / stm;
    vv[0] = v0 / stm;

    for (int j = 1;j < nt;j++) {
        r[j] = gaussnoise(idg);
        xx[j] = xx[j - 1] + d * vv[j - 1];
        vv[j] = c1 * (vv[j - 1] + c2 * r[j]);
    }

    for (int j = 0;j < nt;j++) {
        xx[j] = xx[j]*stm;
        vv[j] = vv[j]*stm;
        if (j == j / f * f) {
            x[j/f] = xx[j];
        }
    }

    delete[] xx;
    delete[] vv;
    delete[] r;
}

double gaussnoise(int idum1) {
    int idum = idum1;
    double  gasdev;
    int iset;
    double fac, gset, rsq, v1, v2;
    double U1, U2;
    iset = 0;
    gset = 0.0;
    if (iset == 0) {
        do {
            U1 = (double)rand() / RAND_MAX;
            U2 = (double)rand() / RAND_MAX;
            v1 = 2. * U1 - 1;
            v2 = 2. * U2 - 1;
            rsq = v1 * v1 + v2 * v2;
        } while (rsq >= 1 || rsq == 0);
        fac = sqrt(-2. * log(rsq) / rsq);
        gset = v1 * fac;
        gasdev = v2 * fac;
        iset = 1;
    }
    else {
        gasdev = gset;
        iset = 0;
    }
    return gasdev;
}
```

Every results produced in brown function are stored in pointer array x and I want to square the difference of m and m-1 and store it into an array which i allocated earlier then print out every elements in it. I'm stuck now with assigning values into arr[m] in every loop(which i comment error in the code block). Can someone help me in this?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and also include the exact error you are facing.

Comment: The shown code in this question does not meet stackoverflow.com's requirements for a [mre]. This means it's unlikely that anyone here can understand what you're asking; but only guess at the most. This question must be [edit]ed to show a minimal example, no more than one or two pages of code (the "minimal" part), that everyone else can cut/paste, compile, run, and execute (the "reproducible" part) ***exactly as shown*** (this includes any ancillary information, like the input to the program). See [ask] for more information.

Comment: One point at which it will fail is when `m >= 61`.

Comment: @lucieon The array did not overflow, the values result from pow(x[m] - x[m - 1], 2.0) did not assigned to arr[m]

Comment: Nothing can assign to `arr` because `arr` doesn't exist.

Comment: @user4581301 sorry, i have just edited my code. Values are not stored in the array even if the array is declared. I do not know what is the problem here

Comment: Pop a debug statement in `while (l <= 100)` and print out the value of `l`.

Comment: Solved the problem. Thanks @user4581301